# What happens when tensorflow.io.read_file fails to read

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've been running a training model that is pulling images from Google Storage using the command **tensorflow.io.read_file**
and relatively often I am seeing the following message:

tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/curl_http_request.cc:596] The transmission  of request 0x7f8c80610d80 (URI: https://storage.googleapis.com/..../images1024x1024%2F51000%2F51249.png) has been stuck at 0 of 0 bytes for 61 seconds and will be aborted. CURL timing information: lookup time: 0.000304 (No error), connect time: 0 (No error), pre-transfer time: 0 (No error), start-transfer time: 0 (No error)

It does not seem to be causing any error, and so I am curious what this call does in the event it fails to read.

Comment: John, instead of using google API, why don't you store the images in drive and access the images from google drive that would be more fast and reliable.

Comment: That’s where the data is, and who’s to say that the problem is with google and not the infrastructure between them and me?